# Autocreate user.config file in deployed app

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, my.settings, user.config, autocreate

I'm coding a VB.Net AddIn for outlook (hence its `VBA` with `.NET`). It's an addition to the standard Calender Item screen. Everything's going fine. But i have a third form with two textboxes, that show me the filepath of the `running assembly` and the `user.config` path with two buttons `"Open in Explorer..."`.

**BUT:**
The user.config file is not there in the beginning. The parent directory and itself get created when I change a setting in the second form and save it for the first time.

I tried to save the usersettings on the form_Initialization method of my main form, with `My.Settings.save()`, but it won't generate the `user.config` file which is odd. That should be the same what I'm doing on the second form.

Can you help me? I need the user.config file right at the start of the third form.

[My Forms (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSxZF.png)

*Code which generates the `user.config` file:*

```
Private Sub BtnSaveSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If (CmbxDebugOption.Text <> "") And (CmbxOnBootActive.Text <> "") Then

            ' save active start option
            If CmbxOnBootActive.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "ja" Then
                My.Settings.ActiveOnStart = True
            ElseIf CmbxOnBootActive.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "nein" Then
                My.Settings.ActiveOnStart = False
            End If

            ' save debug option
            If CmbxDebugOption.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "deaktiviert" Then
                My.Settings.AlwaysDebug = False
                My.Settings.OnetimeDebug = False
            ElseIf CmbxDebugOption.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "nur einmal" Then
                My.Settings.AlwaysDebug = False
                My.Settings.OnetimeDebug = True
            ElseIf CmbxDebugOption.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "immer aktiv" Then
                My.Settings.AlwaysDebug = True
                My.Settings.OnetimeDebug = False
            End If
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If

        ' Close Form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for myself. I created a variable in `My.Settings` called `FirstRunAfterInstall`, which I set to `False` on the first Run of my mainform. I also set the other variables to some default and then save the whole mess. The file will then get written onto your harddisk.

Looks like this:

```
    If My.Settings.FirstRunAfterInstall Then
        My.Settings.FirstRunAfterInstall = False
        My.Settings.ActiveOnStart = False
        My.Settings.OnetimeDebug = False
        My.Settings.AlwaysDebug = False
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
```

`My.Settings.Save()` is the most important part! It flushes some cache. If you forget this part the changes wont get written into the file.

Greetings from Germany,

Christian Hase